# Object Attributes are undefined after routing in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, asynchronous, routes, angular-routing

A newcomer to Angular here. I know similar questions have been asked before and I read too many of them here, answers about AJAX and async programming, but couldn't solve the issue. I want to see the details of the products when I click on 'Details' button, the routing does its job but no values are visible on the page other than static html. So here it is:

This is my details service to get specific details of a product

```
@Injectable()
export class DetailsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  path = "http://localhost:3000/products";

  getProductById(productId: any): Observable<Product> {
    let newPath = this.path
    
    if (productId) {
      newPath += "?id=" + productId;
    }
    console.log(newPath);
    return this.http.get<Product>(newPath).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data) )),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  //handle error func here
```

This is the details component

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Product Details'
  productId: any;
  product: Product;

  constructor(private detailsService: DetailsService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private alertifyService: AlertifyService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.productId = params["id"];
      console.log(this.productId);

      this.detailsService.getProductById(this.productId).subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data;
        console.log(this.product);
        console.log('38')
      });
      console.log(this.productId + " " + typeof this.productId);
    });

}
```

Everything works without any errors or something, but the attributes are not shown on details.component.html which is;

```
<div *ngIf="product">
    <img class="listing-photo" [src]="product.imageUrl"
      alt="Exterior photo of {{product.name}}"/>
    <section class="listing-description">
      <h2 class="listing-heading">{{product.name}}</h2>
      <p class="listing-location">{{product.description}}, {{product.price}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="listing-features">
      <h2 class="section-heading">About this housing location</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Units available: {{product.price}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have wifi: {{product.price}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have laundry: {{product.price}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

The call is made from product.component.html

```
//snippet with ngFor etc
<div class="card-footer">
        <a (click)="addToCart(product)" class="btn btn-primary text-white">Add to cart</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/products',product.id]" class="btn btn-secondary ml-3 ">Details</a>
      </div>
//the rest
```

I tried hundred things if two hundred and I'm lost now. I understand the nature of async programming but can't get it work as intended.

EDIT: Log of console.log(this.product) is as follows:

```
Array(1)
0: 
{category: 'PC Components', categoryId: 1, description: 'Mechanical gaming keyboard with customizable RGB lighting.', id: '1', imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612198188060-c7…xMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: 
Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you please add the log of the `console.log(this.product);` ? Your code can be heavily optimized but as for now it should work.

Comment: I added the log of console.log(this.product). The json file is a dummy json file so it shows random stuff instead of houses etc.

Comment: There it is. The data you received is an array, not a plain object. You need to cycle it using `ngFor`

Comment: Holy mother of god. I don't understand, my service calls a single observable object, why does it return an array?

Comment: It's because of the API call from the backend. changing the path fixed it. Man thank you so much, I've lost some hair to it but it's all good now. I'm all open for any kind of optimizations and suggestions btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have no idea what edit you made to the endpoint I'll keep the same you provided. Regarding my answer, this is the optimized version of your code with comments where needed:

#### Details Service

```
@Injectable()
export class DetailsService {
  private _http = inject(HttpClient); // We directly inject the HttpClient
  private _path = "http://localhost:3000/products";

  // Since you are checking if the productId is given, I made it optional with the ? symbol.
  public getProductById(productId?: string): Observable<Product> {
    // URL created dynamically using the ternary operator
    return this.http.get<Product>(productId ? `${this._path}?id=${productId}` : this.path);
  }
```

#### Details Component

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  // Protected because you are not inheriting this component into another.
  protected title = 'Product Details';
  protected product!: Product;

  // Private since this variable isn't used in the HTML view.
  private _productId!: string;
  
  constructor(
    private _detailsService: DetailsService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this._productId = params["id"];

      // By splitting the service call into a new function, the code will be easier to handle when dealing with large data.
      this._getProductById(this._productId);
    });

  }

  private _getProductById(productId: string): void {
     this._detailsService.getProductById(productId).subscribe(data => {
        this.product = data;
     });
  }
```

}

#### Details Component html

The code is actually fine, I'd just put a touch to it in order to not let the view *explode* if the product has not the data you are trying to display. We achieve this using the `?` key:

```
<div *ngIf="product">
    <img class="listing-photo" [src]="product?.imageUrl"
      alt="Exterior photo of {{product?.name}}"/>
    <section class="listing-description">
      <h2 class="listing-heading">{{product?.name}}</h2>
      <p class="listing-location">{{product?.description}}, {{product?.price}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="listing-features">
      <h2 class="section-heading">About this housing location</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Units available: {{product?.price}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have wifi: {{product?.price}}</li>
        <li>Does this location have laundry: {{product?.price}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

#### Product component html

No need to do anything. I'm not a big fan on using `routerLink` in the component's template, but that's up to you.

Code is not tested nor deeply verified for typos / misspell words, but it should give you a strong starting point, and a fresh codebase.

Few notes:

- Always type **everything**, you have no idea how dangerous *any* can be.
  If you are not sure on what type to use, you can always cast it to `unknown`. A great article about it can be found [here](https://dev.to/smpnjn/type-casting-in-typescript-2m2m)
- Keep the scope of your variable clear, using *private* , *public* and *protected* accordingly.
- if `Product` is a *class* or an *interface* consider changing it to a *type*. It is much more better. To the why, there are a lot of articles that explain it in detail, but long story short:

> Types can be employed with primitive types like type string, whereas interfaces can't be used with primitive types. Types are generally more flexible and expressive.

If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer and articles! I noted everything down for this and further projects. I guess I need more time on understanding the importance of declarations and scopes. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Take you time and don't rush. Angular and Typescript in particular are not easy to learn and master. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see that routing isn't recieving
the changes at the view because is Async calls,
so here is an example to board that.

I used the [official documentacion](https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments), and [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) as an Api.

Also here you have the stackblitz example: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ohx22g)

The most important part is at (TodoDetailComponent) at the end of the example.

**main.ts**

Just boilerplate:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { TodoDetailComponent, TodoListComponent } from './todos.service';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  RouterModule,
  Routes,
  provideRouter,
  RouterLink,
  RouterOutlet,
  RouterLinkActive,
} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Example!</h1>
    <app-todo-list></app-todo-list>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterLink,
    RouterOutlet,
    RouterLinkActive,
    TodoListComponent,
  ],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'todo/:id', component: TodoDetailComponent },
];

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(appRoutes), provideHttpClient()],
});
```

**service,components**

```
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  RouterLink,
  RouterLinkActive,
  RouterOutlet,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

// Interface to manage object
export interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  complete: boolean;
}

// Service to handle data
@Injectable()
export class TodosService {
  private BASE_URL: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getTodos() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}`);
  }
  getTodoById(id: string): Observable<Todo> {
    return this.http.get<Todo>(`${this.BASE_URL}/${id}`);
  }
}

//Full list of todo items
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-todo-list',
  template: `
  <ul>
    @for(todo of todos; track todo.id){
      <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['todo',todo.id]" routerLinkActive="active">
          {{todo.title}}
        </a>
     </li>
    } @empty {
      <li>No items.</li>
    }
  </ul>
  `,
  providers: [TodosService],
  imports: [RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  private _todos: Todo[] = [];
  private todoService: TodosService = inject(TodosService);
  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe({
      next: (response: any) => {
        this.todos = response.slice(0, 4);
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    });
  }
  get todos() {
    return this._todos;
  }
  set todos(todos: Todo[]) {
    this._todos = todos;
  }
}

/**
 * Detail of todo item passed by route param.
 * @see https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments
 */
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-todo-detail',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Back</a>
    <h2>Todo detail</h2>
    @if( todo$ | async; as todoItem) {
      {{todoItem.id}}
      {{todoItem.title}}
      {{todoItem.complete}}
    }
  `,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterLink,
    RouterOutlet,
    RouterLinkActive,
    AsyncPipe,
  ],
  providers: [TodosService],
})
export class TodoDetailComponent {
  todo$!: Observable<Todo>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private todoService: TodosService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todo$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => {
        let todoId = params.get('id');
        return this.todoService.getTodoById('' + todoId);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to understand it row by row, then I shall try it

Comment: The template url is  './details.component.html' on my details.component.ts file. Do I have to write template inside it like you did? Wouldn't it work the way I've written it?

Comment: @romancedawn isn't necessary to write the template like me, in my case is just an example using another approach to do the view, templateUrl is better, for have separated structure